# How do I query Pending posts?

Tags: filters

When I query my posts, I can retrieve all PUBLISHED posts.  For example:

> /wp-json/wp/v2/posts
> ?_fields=yoast_head_json,  date,modified,link,title,author,comment_status,status
> &per_page=100
> &orderby=modified
> &order=desc
> &page=2

How can I query the ones where `status=pending`?  I don't have a status filter in place, but it only returns published posts.

Answer (score 2):

The WordPress REST API includes a 'status' parameter that can be used to retrieve posts based on their status. By default, the API only returns posts with a status of 'publish'. If you want to query 'pending' posts, you'll need to add 'status=pending' to your API call. However, please note that you will need appropriate permissions (typically an authenticated user with author or higher capabilities) to view non-published posts.

So your API call would look something like this:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=pending&_fields=yoast_head_json,date,modified,link,title,author,comment_status,status&per_page=100&orderby=modified&order=desc&page=2
```

Remember, the WordPress REST API respects all privacy and capability controls, so make sure your API call is authenticated with a user that has the correct permissions to view pending posts. Otherwise, you'll get a response that you're not authorized to view the resource.

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried that filter, but receive a status is forbidden error.
https://www.beringer.net//wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=pending&_fields=yoast_head_json,date,modified,link,title,author,comment_status,status&per_page=100&orderby=modified&order=desc&page=2

I can confirm that I'm an admin to the wordpress site, and can see posts with all statuses in the same web browser session.  I'm assuming that I can simply call these endpoints from the same web browser, once I've authenticated.  Is that correct?

Comment: The WordPress REST API doesn't rely on your browser's session to maintain authentication. You need to explicitly provide authentication with each API call.

If you're making these requests from the browser, one way to handle authentication is by using nonce. Add a nonce to your API call as a parameter like this:

/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=pending&_wpnonce=YOUR_NONCE_HERE

You can generate a nonce in WordPress using wp_create_nonce('wp_rest').